# ChannelFactory method call increse memory

Tags: winforms, wcf, channelfactory

I have an `winform` application which consumes windows service, i user `ChannelFactory`
to connect to service, problem is when i call service method using channel the memory usage increase and after 
method execute memory not go down(even after form close), i call `GC.Collect` but no change

channel Create class

```
public class Channel1
{
List<ChannelFactory> chanelList = new List<ChannelFactory>();
ISales salesObj;

public ISales Sales
{
    get
    {
        if (salesObj == null)
        {
            ChannelFactory<ISales> saleschannel = new ChannelFactory<ISales>("SalesEndPoint");
            chanelList.Add(saleschannel);
            salesObj = saleschannel.CreateChannel();
        }
        return salesObj;
    }
}

public void CloseAllChannels()
{
    foreach (ChannelFactory chFac in chanelList)
    {
        chFac.Abort();
        ((IDisposable)chFac).Dispose();            
    }
    salesObj = null;
}
}
```

base class

```
public class Base:Form
    {    
       public Channel1 channelService = new Channel1();        
       public Channel1 CHANNEL
       {
           get
           {
               return channelService;
           }
       }                  
    }
```

winform class
Form1:Base

```
 private void btnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable _dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                gvAccounts.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                _dt = CHANNEL.Sales.GetDatatable();
                gvAccounts.DataSource = _dt;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {    
                MessageBox.Show("Error Occurred while processing...\n" + ex.Message, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
            finally
            {
                CHANNEL.CloseAllChannels();
                _dt.Dispose();
                //GC.Collect();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just because you dispose something does not mean it will automatically get collected by the GC next Collection. Why do you feel you need to manually call the GC and not just let the program manage itself? I highly recommend you read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx) to help you understand how the garbage collector works.

Comment: In fact you still have live references to your channels! You never release the reference that is held as an item in `Channel1.chanelList`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain how can i release channel references

Comment: @ScottChamberlain does CHANNEL.CloseAllChannels() not release reference

Comment: Why are you creating a ChannelFactory every time you want a channel?  Simply create the ChannelFactory once, and then call `CreateChannel()` on the factory when you need a new channel.  I'd recommend creating the channel, using it, and then closing it.  There's no point in having (potentially) several copies of the same ChannelFactory at once.

Comment: @Tim can you post an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track in terms of using `ChannelFactory<T>`, but your implementation is a bit off.

`ChannelFactory<T>` creates a factory for generating channels of type T.  This is a relatively expensive operation (as compared to just creating a channel from the existing factory), and is generally done once per life of the application (usually at start).  You can then use that factory instance to create as many channels as your application needs.

Generally, once I've created the factory and cached it, when I need to make a call to the service I get a channel from the factory, make the call, and then close/abort the channel.

Using your posted code as a starting point, I would do something like this:

```
public class Channel1
{

    ChannelFactory<ISales> salesChannel;

    public ISales Sales
    {
        get
        {
            if (salesChannel == null)
            {
                salesChannel = new ChannelFactory<ISales>("SalesEndPoint");
            }
            return salesChannel.CreateChannel();
        }
    }       
}
```

Note that I've replaced the `salesObj` with `salesChannel` (the factory).  This will create the factory the first time it's called, and create a new channel from the factory every time.

Unless you have a particular requirement to do so, I wouldn't keep track of the different channels, especially if follow the open/do method/close approach.

In your form, it'd look something like this:

```
private void btnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataTable _dt = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        gvAccounts.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        ISales client = CHANNEL.Sales
        _dt = client.GetDatatable();
        gvAccounts.DataSource = _dt;
        ((ICommunicationObject)client).Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {    
        ((ICommunicationObject)client).Abort();
        MessageBox.Show("Error Occurred while processing...\n" + ex.Message, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
}
```

The code above gets a new ISales channel from the factory in CHANNEL, executes the call, and then closes the channel.  If an exception happens, the channel is aborted in the catch block.

I would avoid using `Dispose()` out of the box on the channels, as the implementation in the framework is flawed and will throw an error if the channel is in a faulted state.  If you really want to use `Dispose()` and force the garbage collection, you can - but you'll have to work around the WCF dispose issue.  Google will give you a number of workarounds (google WCF Using for a start).